# How to add curly brackets and hyphen to a yaml in python

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

I have a python script that generates yaml files with pyyaml and I need something like this in the output:

```yaml
key: {{- something }}
```

When I try to add this in my dictionary object

```py
{ "key": "{{- something }}" }
```

the output will be this:

```yaml
key: '{{- something }}'
```

Is there a workaround where I can put braces into the dictionary value? Thanks!

I tried string formatting or putting the `{{- something }}` into a variable but it always prints it with the `''` marks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there a particular reason why you want `{{- something}}` not to be quoted? Because if you want that to be a literal value, it needs to be marked in some way so that yaml readers don't try to interpret it as a dictionary in flow style.

Comment: Do you want this to be a YAML literal, i.e. you want to manually insert a piece of YAML markup; or do you want this to be the string “{{- something }}”?

Comment: Is `key: {{- something }}` valid YAML?  That seems to me to be the question here.  I only use the simplest of YAML syntax, so I don't know the answer, and I'm quite curious.  Typing that value into a couple of online YAML syntax checkers suggests that it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with PyYAML or any conforming YAML implementation.

This:

```yaml
key: {{- something }}
```

is invalid YAML because `{` starts a flow mapping, while `-` starts a block sequence item. While you can nest flow mappings, you cannot put a block sequence item into a flow mapping.

You cannot use a YAML implementation to create invalid YAML, as the point of a YAML implementation is to always output valid YAML.

You are probably not actually generating YAML files, but Jinja templates that compile to YAML files (guessing from the fact that `{{- something}}` is a typical Jinja construct). A YAML implementation cannot help you generate files that need to be processed by a templating engine to become valid YAML files.

There are some workarounds. For example, you could output

```yaml
key: _something_
```

and then post-process the output to replace `_something_` with `{{- something}}`. I chose `_something_` because that's a format PyYAML does not quote by default.